# How To Change The Maximum File Size Upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

how do you change the maximum upload file size, i want people to only be aloud to upload 25mb video files on my site, can you do that?

like in a .htaccess File But Without Getting A 500 ERROR

UPDATE: http://www.triggervid.com/

when a user uploaded's a video i want it to say Something like - Sorry The file you are trying to upload is to big or it exceeds the maximum limit, only if it is over 25mb. sorry im not very Well At explaining things :)

P.S  im using PHP mainly

Comment: You'll have to give us more details.  What are files being uploaded to? What software/programming languages are you using? What do you want to happen if someone tries to upload a file that's too big?

Comment: Please don't use capitalisation on each word - it's difficult to read. As for your issue, what technology are you using? You can try `LimitRequestBody` directive in your .htaccess file - but I'm never tried it myself.  The issue here is that it controls the overall request size, not the file size.  So, if your user can upload two files on the same form, this limit will be applied to the total content size, not each file separately.

Comment: Generally, you *only* capitalize the first word in a sentence in English. Unless the word in question is a proper noun, such as a name. So you would capitalize Jarrad and English and Stack Overflow because they're all names.

Answer (score 2):

In your php.ini file you can modify these lines as appropriate:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do changes in php,ini file ..
by default for upload_max_filesize, it is 32Mb and for post_max_size it is 16Mb for Apache 2.0 but you an change as per your requirement

upload_max_filesize = desired file size.. (ie 5M)
post_max_size = desired file size.. (ie 5M)
)