# How do increase the max file upload size using php on apache web server?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Change The Maximum File Size Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581279/how-to-change-the-maximum-file-size-upload)

I want to make the max file upload size to be 20MB, I know I need to use *htaccess*, but where to put it, I am using windows web server.

Can you tell me in which repository I should put that file?

Comment: It's php.ini you need, not .htaccess

Comment: Asked tons of times on here. Flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Find your php.ini file and change the value of upload_max_filesize and set it to the desired value. Then restart your webserver.